# If you save a DataFrame to disk, will Spark load that data if you use that DataFrame lower in the script?

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If you load some data, compute a DataFrame, write that to disk and then use the DataFrame later... assuming it isn't still cached in RAM (lets say there wasn't enough), would Spark be smart enough to load the data from disk rather than recompute the DataFrame from the original data?

For example:

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet('data/df1.parquet')
df2 = spark.read.parquet('data/df2.parquet')

joined = df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id)
joined.write.parquet('data/joined.parquet')

computed = joined.select('id').withColummn('double_total', 2 * joined.total)
computed.write.parquet('data/computed.parquet')
```

Under the right circumstances, when we store `computed`, will it load the `joined` DataFrame from `data/joined.parquet` or will it always re-compute by loading/joining `df1`/`df2` if it isn't currently caching `joined`?

Comment: So effectively you are asking if write.parquet counts as an action or not to the join transformation. I will be curious to see the answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `joined` dataframe points to `df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id)`. As far as I know the parquet writer will not cause any changes to that reference therefore in order to load the parquet data you need to construct a new Spark reader with `spark.reader.parquet(...)`.

You can verify the above claim from the [DataFrameWriter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala) code (check parquet/save methods) which returns Unit and not modifying somehow the reference of the source dataframe. Finally to answer your question in the above example the joined dataframe will be calculated once for `joined.write.parquet('data/joined.parquet')` and once for `computed.write.parquet('data/computed.parquet')`

Comment: Thanks! This is surprising. I would have expected it to use the version on disk if it has to recalculate, if it thinks that will be faster.

Comment: Well as far as I know the only way to utilize parquet is to relaoad it again with reader as already mentioned. Also consider the fact that after writing to parquet this data is stored in memory and/or in the final partitions therefore if you dont use any wide transformation Spark will not load everything from scratch instead will use the stored information and the existing lineage

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. But I often test the limits of the RAM of the machine(s) I'm working on, so it does often have to recompute and it would be cool to load from there when it does. Loading a couple of columns in a wide DataFrame from Parquet makes feasible computation that is simply impossible otherwise. I'll continue to load manually after storing, thanks!

Comment: Ok could also try to cache it and immediately after checkpointing.